# CodeIgniter: Very slow processing, taking 4-5 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My codeigniter application responding in 4-5 seconds.Environment is wamp( echo phpinfo(); with in 50ms). I have tried the following things.

echo "test"; exit; on main **index.php** : TTFB time ~ 100ms
echo "test"; exit; on main **application/config/constant.php** : TTFB time ~ 500ms
echo "test"; exit; on main **application/config/config.php** : TTFB time ~ 600ms
echo "test"; exit; on main **application/config/database.php** : TTFB time ~ 2s
echo "test"; exit; on main **application/config/route.php** : TTFB time ~ 1.5s
echo "test"; exit; on main **application/controller/main.php** : TTFB time ~ 4.8s
echo "test"; exit; on main **application/controller/secondary.php**(with calling of models) : TTFB time ~ 4.9s

I have run the same application on another system, it is working fine, the system having the same environment ( i.e same system architecture and apache modules ), Unable to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the server stack configs for the full stack?
Personally I'd recommend you use AMPPS over WAMP (I switched a while ago) or even better use a Vagrant box like Laravel Homestead (works with any PHP project, not just Laravel) as it is Unix based on top of your OS.

Comment: Maybe your system is busy ? Updates ...

Comment: My guess: anti virus program maybe? Disable real time protection and see if it helps.

Comment: @Brewal i have updated the system, problem still exist.

Comment: check your controller application/controller/main.php. check with die() function on each and every line. You will get your issue.